# Why is this ancestor code not working - Prolog

Tags: prolog

```
parent(jill, john).  
parent(john, pam).  
parent(pam, bob).  
parent(tom, bob).  
parent(tom, liz).  
parent(bob, ann).  
parent(bob, pat).  
parent(pat, jim).  

female(jill).      
female(pam).  
female(liz).  
female(ann).  
female(pat).  
male(jim).  
male(john).  
male(tom).  
male(bob).  

mother(X,Y) :- female(X) , parent(X,Y).  
father(X,Y) :- male(X), parent(X,Y).  
offspring(X,Y) :-  parent(Y,X).  
sister(X,Y) :- female(X), female(Y), parent(Z,X), parent(Z,Y), not(X=Y).  
ancestor(X, Y) :- parent(X,Z), ancestor(Z,Y).
```

This is the whole code plus some other stuff not related to the ancestor part. When I try to test it in swipl, the ancestor code gives me false. I am trying ancestor(pat,jim). and `ancestor(X,jim)`. If I use `;` instead of `,` in the ancestor code, it kind of works but repeats names when a person has both parents in the list.

Comment: Do you know what `,` means versus `;`?

Comment: So what's the simplest input where you *can* infer `ancestor/2` from these rules? (Answer: There are none.)

Comment: Your definition of `ancestor` is a single, recursive clause: `ancestor(X, Y) :- parent(X,Z), ancestor(Z,Y).` . This can only either keep recursing, or terminate in failure. You need another clause that isn't recursive.

Comment: @lurker I know they mean "and" "or". I was just confused because that is the code I found googling it but did not work. I already got it to work thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cases like this, `trace` is your friend:

```
?- trace.
true.

[trace]  ?- ancestor(pat, jim).
   Call: (8) ancestor(pat, jim) ? creep
   Call: (9) parent(pat, _3162) ? creep
   Exit: (9) parent(pat, jim) ? creep
   Call: (9) ancestor(jim, jim) ? creep
   Call: (10) parent(jim, _3162) ? creep
   Fail: (10) parent(jim, _3162) ? creep
   Fail: (9) ancestor(jim, jim) ? creep
   Fail: (8) ancestor(pat, jim) ? creep
false.
```

See what happens? You defined `ancestor(X,Y)` as having two requirements: First, `X` must be the parent of some middleman `Z`, and then `Z` also needs to be an ancestor of `Y`. Since `pat` is the parent of `jim`, this requires `jim` to be his own ancestor, which he isn't.

One possible solution is to define an ancestor as *either* a direct parent *or* the parent of another ancestor:

```
ancestor(X, Y) :- parent(X, Y).
ancestor(X, Y) :- parent(X, Z), ancestor(Z, Y).
```

Let's test:

```
[trace]  ?- ancestor(pat, jim).
   Call: (8) ancestor(pat, jim) ? creep
   Call: (9) parent(pat, jim) ? creep
   Exit: (9) parent(pat, jim) ? creep
   Exit: (8) ancestor(pat, jim) ? creep
```

So, we're good with `pat` and `jim`, because they are in a direct `parent` relation. What about the recursive case?

```
[trace]  ?- ancestor(tom,pat).
   Call: (8) ancestor(tom, pat) ? creep
   Call: (9) parent(tom, pat) ? creep
   Fail: (9) parent(tom, pat) ? creep
   Redo: (8) ancestor(tom, pat) ? creep
   Call: (9) parent(tom, _3168) ? creep
   Exit: (9) parent(tom, bob) ? creep
   Call: (9) ancestor(bob, pat) ? creep
   Call: (10) parent(bob, pat) ? creep
   Exit: (10) parent(bob, pat) ? creep
   Exit: (9) ancestor(bob, pat) ? creep
   Exit: (8) ancestor(tom, pat) ? creep
true .
```